# function declaration with STL in header c++

Tags: c++

I am pretty new to the concept of splitting a program into `header` and etc. Normally, it goes ok, but in this case I have a whole bunch of errors if i try to do next:

Suppose I have a .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //some code here
}

map <char, char> create(vector <char> &one, vector <char> &two) {
    //some code here
}

vector <char> conc(string phrase) {
    // some code here
} 

vector <char> result(vector<char> three, map <char, char> code) {
    // some code here
}
```

In `Header.h` I have:

```
map <char, char> create(vector <char> &one, vector <char> &two);
vector <char> conc(string phrase);
vector <char> result(vector<char> three, map <char, char> code);
```

Which are just function declarations.. If I put them in .cpp the program works great, but if in Header.h - it does not. Could you, please tell what I am missing here?

I am reading about the concept of splitting on cprogramming.com, but they never had an example with STL. Thank you!

Comment: .h file should include all required headers. Also, it should contain [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: @n0rd, the `.h` file shouldn't contain headers that aren't needed for the compiler to understand the declarations. So in the case the header should include `vector`, `map` and `string`, but not the others. If you get in the habit of `#include`-ing too much, then you'll end up with massive compile times through recursive inclusions in many translation units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `using namespace std;` in cpp file, but not in header (and don't use it in header), so you should use fully qualified type names:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

std::map <char, char> create(std::vector <char> &one, std::vector <char> &two);
std::vector <char> conc(std::string phrase);
std::vector <char> result(std::vector<char> three, std::map <char, char> code);

#endif // HEADER_H
```

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly an educated guess since you didn't post the actual error nor the whole code.

You're missing `std::` before every STL class name since you should not use `using` statement in header files.

Example:
`std::map <char, char> create(std::vector <char> &one, std::vector <char> &two);`

Also make sure you have the proper include statement at the top of your header file (`<vector>`, etc...).

Comment: Thanks, but aren't these '#include' redundant if added to Header? Looks like they are not necessary for work. I mean include for containers

Comment: In your case it *looks* redundant because you include `Header.h` after `<vector>`, ..., in your cpp file so the compiler knows those classes when reading your header file. But if you had first included `Header.h` it would not have compiled.

Comment: @VVG, .h file must be usable on its own. If you don't include container headers, you become dependent on order of `#include` in your .cpp file.